# Passing state between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I wrote a component with a state `chosenGenre` and inside it, there is a function that changes the state according to the clicked button.

I would like to take the updated state (which is `string`) and use it in another component.

This is the component in which the state is declared:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Genre from './Genre';
import './GenreSelectPage.css';
import Blues from '../Blues.png';
import Classical from '../Classical.png'; 
import Country from '../Country.png';

export default class GenreSelectPage extends Component{

    state = {
        chosenGenre: ""
    }

    handleClick = (genreName) => {
        this.setState({ chosenGenre: genreName });
    }

    render() {
        return(
        <div className = "GenreSelectPage">
        <h3>Select your desired Kollab Room Genre</h3>
        <Genre genrePicture= {Blues} genreClicked = {()=>this.handleClick("Blues")}/>
        <Genre genrePicture= {Classical} genreClicked = {()=>this.handleClick("Classical")}/>
        <Genre genrePicture= {Country} genreClicked = {()=>this.handleClick("Country")}/>
        </div>
        ) 
     }
}
```

And this is the new component for which I want to use the `chosenGenre` state from `GenreSelectPage` component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GenreSelectPage from './GenreSelectPage';

export default class InRoomPage extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <div className = "InRoomPage">
                <p>Welcome to {GenreSelectPage.state.chosenGenre} page</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

What should I change inside the:

```
<p>Welcome to {GenreSelectPage.state.chosenGenre} room !</p>
```

So it will work?

Comment: What is the relation between the above two components? do they have same parent component?

Comment: Do these components share a common parent? or these components have different parents?

Comment: paste your Genre component code too.

Comment: They do not have the same parent.

Comment: are these two different pages?

Comment: @eramit2010 yes

Answer (score 9):

**Common parent:**  ( You can lift your state up one level )

If these components have a common parent, then you need to move this state one step up into the common parent component and pass the handler to update the state into `GenreSelectPage` and pass the state has `props`  into `InRoomPage`.

**Have no common parent:** ( Can use Redux )

You need to use **Redux**, where you state will be maintained in one central store and you can **connect** to this store from any component from any part of the component tree and get the state into its props.

usage : https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

**Moving components under the same parent:**

You can create a new component say **componentParent** (Use name according to your app ), store your state in this component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GenreSelectPage from './GenreSelectPage';
import InRoomPage from './InRoomPage';

export default class componentParent extends Component {

    state = {
      chosenGenre: ""
    }

    handleClick = (genreName) => {
      this.setState({ chosenGenre: genreName });
    }

    render() {
      return(
        <div className = "InRoomPage">
          <GenreSelectPage clickHandler={this.handleClick}></GenreSelectPage>
          <InRoomPage chosenGenre={this.state.chosenGenre}></InRoomPage>
        </div>
      )
    }
}
```

also please check [Context API](https://hackernoon.com/how-do-i-use-react-context-3eeb879169a2)

Comment: They do not have the same parent, can you please provide an example how to put them under the same parent ? or how to use Redux in my case ?

Comment: You left out a pretty significant middleground between prop drilling and going full-blown redux: the context api.

Comment: @collin I agree

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G in this case, if I want to use another state from a different component inside InRoonComponent, I won't be able to do that unless I add the state to this componentParent. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @I.zv There are two ways one is what you said and another is you can use componentParent inside that component and pass what you want has props.

Comment: @shakespear thanks for the edit, helps to improve the answer.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, the common way to share state between components is to use Redux, MobX is another alternative.

Here's a basic example of a Redux application. Two components, one which writes a value to the Redux store, and the other which reads a value from the Redux store.

The key parts of setting up Redux are:

- `<Provider>` - This wraps your entire app and supplies the store, also known as a reducer
- reducer - This is where you set an initial state, and return an updated version of the state based on actions
- actions - Actions are just objects with values you can read from to update and return a new state
- `connect` - This function connects your component to redux, its first two arguments are `mapStateToProps`, and `mapDispatchToProps`
- `mapStateToProps` - This parameter is a function that allows you to read from the state (redux store), and it will put the values into `this.props`
- `mapDispatchToProps` - Dispatch actions to update the store is done from here

Your reducer, actions, and selectors are normally in separate files, so they can be shared between components easily.

The components below would be in separate files as well, and you'd `export default` the `connect` portion of each.

#### Demo

```js
const { Component } = React;
const { applyMiddleware, createStore } = Redux;
const { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux;


/*********************/
/** GenreSelectPage **/
/*********************/
class GenreSelectPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.selectGenre = this.selectGenre.bind(this);
  }
  selectGenre(e) {
    const genre = e.target.value;
    this.props.selectGenre(genre);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>GenreSelectPage Component</h3>
        <select onChange={this.selectGenre}>
          <option value="">Select a genre</option>
          <option value="blues">Blues</option>
          <option value="classical">Classical</option>
          <option value="country">Country</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// Write to store
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({ selectGenre: (genre) => dispatch({type: 'SELECT_GENRE', genre}) })

// Connect to store
const GenreSelectComponent = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(GenreSelectPage);


/*******************/
/**  InRoomPage   **/
/*******************/
class InRoomPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>InRoomPage Component</h3>
        <p>{this.props.genre}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// Read from store
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ genre: state.genre });
// Connect to store
const InRoomComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(InRoomPage);

/*******************/
/**     REDUX     **/
/*******************/
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  genre: null
}
const reducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SELECT_GENRE':
      return {
        ...state,
        genre: action.genre
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
const store = createStore(reducer);

// Provider (from Redux) wraps around your entire app
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <GenreSelectComponent />
    <InRoomComponent />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.1/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/6.0.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try any of the below things

a. Move the state to the common parent component of `GenreSelectPage` and `InRoomPage`. Pass the `handleGenereChange` method to the `GenreSelectPage` as props and set the state in the `parentComponent`. Send the state value as props to `InRoomPage`. This is called lifting the state up. More details at https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

b. Use Redux. More info available on https://almerosteyn.com/2016/08/redux-explained-again